# Dealing with date in prolog

Tags: date, datetime, prolog, stamp

How to make a program where you can insert a date, and after add some days (suppose + 20 days) to obtain a new date?

EXAMPLE:

```
?- write a date in this format(YYYY-MM-DD.): 2020-01-15.
The new date is : 2020-02-04
```

I think that I should use this predefined predicates: date time stamp, stamp date time and date time value but I dont succeed to manage it.

I found below code :

```
goes :-
    write('Please enter your birthday [YYYY-MM-DD]'),
    nl,
    read_string(Birthday),
    parse_time(Birthday, Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, 'UTC'),
    DateTime = date(Year, Month, Day, _, _, _, _, _, _),
    print('Year: '), print(Year), nl,
    print('Month: '), print(Month), nl,
    print('Day: '), print(Day), nl.

read_string(String) :-
    current_input(Input),
    read_line_to_codes(Input, Codes),
    string_codes(String, Codes).
```

and get this:

```
?- goes.
Please enter your birthday [YYYY-MM-DD] |: 2010-07-05.
false.
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried & explain how it comes up short?

Comment: I found bellow code :
goes :-
    write('Please enter your birthday [YYYY-MM-DD]'), nl,
    read_string(Birthday),
    parse_time(Birthday, Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, 'UTC'),
    DateTime = date(Year, Month, Day, _, _, _, _, _, _),
    print('Year: '), print(Year), nl,
    print('Month: '), print(Month), nl,
    print('Day: '), print(Day), nl.

read_string(String) :-
    current_input(Input),
    read_line_to_codes(Input, Codes),
    string_codes(String, Codes).   and get this :?- goes.
Please enter your birthday [YYYY-MM-DD]
|: 2010-07-05.
false.

Comment: What version of Prolog are you using that has these predefined predicates?

Comment: @CalinBorzin - Please don't put code in comments. It's almost useless there. Edit your question (like I did).

Comment: @CalinBorzin - which predicate is causing your program to fail?

Comment: @ScottHunter I use SWI- Prolog

Comment: @Enigmativity , thanks for advice, I am new user in stackoverflow. It seems like the code fails in line "parse_time(Birthday, Stamp)", after that line I get false

Comment: @CalinBorzin - where is the `parse/2` predicate definition?

Answer (score 2):

The building blocks are all there:

```erlang
?- date_time_stamp(date(2020,4,15,0,0,0,Off,TZ,DST),TimeStamp).
Off = -7200,
TZ = 'CEST',
DST = true,
TimeStamp = 1586901600.0.

?- NDays=20,Next is $TimeStamp+60*60*24*NDays.
NDays = 20,
Next = 1588629600.0,
TimeStamp = 1586901600.0.

?- stamp_date_time($Next,DT,local).
DT = date(2020, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0.0, -7200, 'CEST', true),
Next = 1588629600.0.
```

The notation `$TimeStamp` is a SWI-Prolog handly feature of the REPL (that is, the interactive interpreter), that give us the last value that the variable `TimeStamp` has been binded.

Clearly, you're better to encapsulate the complexity in your own applicative interface.

The documentation also hints a different way, just add the number of days to the day field of the date/9 structure, to get the appropriate timestamp.

Then the whole could be:

```erlang
goes :-
    write('enter date as `YYYY-MM-DD.`:'),
    read(YYYY-MM-DD),
    D1 is DD+20,
    date_time_stamp(date(YYYY,MM,D1,0,0,0,_,_,_),Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp,D,local),
    date_time_value(date,D,DV),
    format('result date:~w', [DV]).
```