# Incrementing datetime by second

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to take a datestring, e.g. `2020-03-04 06:22:59.012315131` and increment it by one second so it becomes `2020-03-04 06:23:00`. The ms ending part doesn't matter.

Using the `date` library I have been able to successfully increment the time by minutes.

```
:- use_module(library(date)).

get_dt(Datestring, Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, X) :-
    parse_time(Datestring, Stamp1),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp1, DateTime1, 'UTC'),
    DateTime1 = date(Y1, M1, D1, H1, Mn1, S1, _, _, _),
    Mn2 is Mn1 + X,
    date_time_stamp(date(Y1, M1, D1, H1, Mn2, S1, _, _, _), Stamp2),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp2, DateTime2, 'UTC'),
    DateTime2 = date(Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, _, _, _).
```

When running the following it successfully increments the time to the next hour, e.g. Hour 6 to Hour 7 and resets the Minute value from 22 to 0. This justs adds `38` to the Mn value.

```
?- get_dt('2020-03-04 06:22:59.012315131', Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, 38).
Y = 2020,
M = 3,
D = 4,
H = 7,
Mn = 0,
S = 59.012315034.
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with Seconds instead of Minutes, and to increment Second of 59 by the value of 1 to 60, so that the Minute value will increment by 1. However, when incrementing seconds by 1 so the minute has to increment as seconds is now 60, it increments Minute by 2 from 22 to 24. I can't understand why.

```
:- use_module(library(date)).

get_dt(Datestring, Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, X) :-
    parse_time(Datestring, Stamp1),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp1, DateTime1, 'UTC'),
    DateTime1 = date(Y1, M1, D1, H1, Mn1, S1, _, _, _),
    S2 is S1 + X,
    date_time_stamp(date(Y1, M1, D1, H1, Mn1, S2, _, _, _), Stamp2),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp2, DateTime2, 'UTC'),
    DateTime2 = date(Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, _, _, _).
```

```
?- get_dt('2020-03-04 06:22:59.012315131', Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, 1).
Y = 2020,
M = 3,
D = 4,
H = 6,
Mn = 24,
S = 0.012315034.
```

EDIT: This last example above should show a Mn value of `23`, or I think it should anyway.

Thanks

Comment: I tried, and have experienced the same behaviour you describe, I think it's a bug... do you mind to report it on https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/ ? A link to this post should be enough

Comment: A valid second is in the range 0-59. 60 is invalid (leading to "garbage in, garbage out"). To add seconds safely, use e.g.: ?- D = datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59), datetime_add(D, 2 secs, D2).
D = datetime(2021,12,31,23,59,59),
D2 = datetime(2022,1,1,0,0,1).

Comment: Continuing discussion here [link](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/bug-date-library/5118) for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from [Discourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/bug-date-library/5118/4?u=jan)

Not sure why, but it works fine if you actually pass on the timezone info:

```
:- use_module(library(date)).

get_dt(Datestring, Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, X) :-
    parse_time(Datestring, Stamp1),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp1, DateTime1, 'UTC'),
    DateTime1 = date(Y1, M1, D1, H1, Mn1, S1, Off, TZ, DST),
    S2 is S1 + X,
    date_time_stamp(date(Y1, M1, D1, H1, Mn1, S2, Off, TZ, DST), Stamp2),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp2, DateTime2, 'UTC'),
    DateTime2 = date(Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, _, _, _).
```

```
?- get_dt('2020-03-04 06:22:59.012315131', Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, 1).
Y = 2020,
M = 3,
D = 4,
H = 6,
Mn = 23,
S = 0.012315034.
```

Surely passing on is a good idea.   I'm afraid I do not have time right now to figure out what exactly is supposed to happen if you pass variables.

Surely if you want to compute second offsets, doing so based on the time stamp is a lot easier.   The non-normalized values for the time stamp are useful if you want to change a date by a month or a year as these do not have a defined number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I found another cleaner solution using [Dealing with date in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218340/dealing-with-date-in-prolog)

I'm still interested in why my previous code didn't work though.

```
get_dt(Datestring, Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, X) :-
    parse_time(Datestring, Stamp),
    Stamp1 is Stamp + X,
    stamp_date_time(Stamp1, DateTime, 'UTC'),
    DateTime = date(Y, M, D, H, Mn, S, _, _, _).
```